# Spark get a column as sequence for usage in zeppelin select form

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-zeppelin

I have a dataframe from which I want to select column(s) as seq to be used in zeppelin Select form.

This is how the select form works:

[image: basic select form example]

Select form requires

```
required: Iterable[(Object, String)]
```

what I have I got is

```
val test_seq = data.select("file", "id").collect().map(x => (x.get(0), x.get(1).toString)).toSeq
```

Which is in form

```
found: Seq[(Any, String)]
```

And is not usable in the form. I have not yet figured out how do I get the the column(s) out of the dataframe in correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting a tuple of object and string from the RDD, and use `toIterable` to convert to `Iterable[(Object, String)]`:

```
val testIter = data.select("file", "id").collect().map(
    x => (x.getAs[Object](0), x.getAs[String](1))
).toIterable
```

Comment: Works great thanks. And for people searching for this in the future, don't try this with a huge dataframe it makes the page unresponsive :)